# Sleeping Pill Overdose

Tags: human-physiology

How does an overdose of sleeping pills kill? 
What are the body's reactions to an overdose?
In an article published in ScienceDaily, I read that "Sleeping pills owe half their benefit to the placebo effect". 
So what constituents of a sleeping pill, when taken in excess, lead to a negative reaction?

Comment: Note that "Sleeping pills owe half their benefit to the placebo effect" is a statement about the efficacy of placebo for helping sleep; it says little about the actual effects of the drugs and does *not* mean that sleeping pills are just placebo and does *not* mean they do not have physiological effects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some [hypnotics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypnotic) — the active component of sleeping medications — act as central nervous system (CNS) [depressants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depressant), which in turn [depress breathing or respiration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypoventilation), especially when mixed with other drugs, such as alcohol.

If your breathing slows sufficiently and is [arrested](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Respiratory_arrest), as can be caused by an overdose of CNS depressants, your vital organs will be starved for oxygen, which in turn can lead to brain damage and — ultimately — death.

Comment: (+1) Piggybacking to say you'd have a vicious cycle of respiratory depression reducing blood oxygen saturation, causing ischaemia and poor perfusion in the respiratory centre (RC), killing the neurons there and in turn causing more respiratory depression. At some point, when all your RC neurons are dead, you stop breathing completely. This would be after the death of other areas of the brain due to the extensive blood supply of the RC. Also I'd note that most hypnotics depress the CNS by facilitation of GABAergic transmission.